# What should be the generic font family for Font-Awesome fonts?

Tags: css, fonts, sonarqube, font-awesome

I'm using FontAwesome 4.7 in one of my project and we have SonarQube integration. At few places in my custom CSS files, I've to provide Font-Family manually like:

```
.calendar-wrapper:after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f073';
  position: absolute;
  right: 9px;
  top: 9px;
}
```

But at this line, SonarQube shows me bug:
Unexpected missing generic font family ([Rule Here](https://rules.sonarsource.com/css/RSPEC-4649))

What should be the generic font-family for FontAwesome? I looked everywhere on the internet but didn't found any solution yet.

Comment: There are no generic font for that. If you want to pass the test, just put anything like serif. Or disable the test if possible

Answer (score 21):

'FontAwesome' is a custom font, so sonarqube is asking to add generic font to fallback to.
Adding a generic font like "sans-serif" will be sufficinet.

```
.calendar-wrapper:after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
  content: '\f073';
  position: absolute;
  right: 9px;
  top: 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the official documentation, you need to have a generic font in your `font` and `font-family` values. Generic fonts means `serif` or `sans-serif` and they works a fallback fonts in case the main font is not reachable which could be because of some privacy settings on user's browser.

Please check the official documentation here: https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/font-family-no-missing-generic-family-keyword/